# What is the difference between друг с другом and друг другу?

Tags: выбор-слова, наречия

I read the following sentences:

> Две девочки разговаривают друг с другом.
>
> Мужчины помогают друг другу.
>
> Они танцуют друг с другом.

I think the meaning in each sentence is something like the followings:

> The two girls talk with each other.
>
> Men is helping each other.
>
> They are dancing together.

But I don't get when to use `друг с другом` and `друг другу`. What is the difference between them?

Comment: The two girls talk each other?!? That is not grammatical. Try instead that the two girls talk with each other. And in the third sentence they dance with each other. So the с becomes "with" quite directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's simply Dative vs. Instrumental case issue. There is natural (although hidden in your translation) correspondence here:

> dance **with** --> Instrumental case --> танцевать друг с друг**ом**
>   help **to** --> Dative case --> помогать друг друг**у**

The verb *разговаривать* yet differs: in Russian *разговаривать* denotes "cross-personal" communication exclusively, so it requires Instrumental "with". If you need Dative "to", you have to use imperfective form "*говорить*" (note that both are OK, though slightly different: *говорить друг другу* and *говорить друг с другом*).

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on verb syntax. Compare:

> разговаривать (с кем?) - с другом
>
> помогать (кому?) - другу
>
> танцевать (с кем?) - с другом